# Sugar CRM 'Edit sub menu' Disappeared

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

In one of my SugarCRM sudenly all the edit submenu not showing anymore including the arrow.
[image]

It has only Edit button add the moment. This is happening for entire site. I haven't edit any code, hence wondering if it happened because of any settings.

Thanks for your help.

Kind regards

Comment: Have you defined any roles for your user?

Comment: Yes, the role seems fine. I have another instance where this is fine.

Comment: Check permission of you dir as per standards and clear the cache http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Administration/Platform_Management/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux/

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Setting the permission to the directories helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the answer here. So in future it can help to someone.

Check the permission once you installed the crm on server as per standard given here http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Administration/Platform_Management/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux/